# How to Calculate Average in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am building Analytical solution and need to calculate - Average Number of Users accessed reports per day in Power BI (DAX)

Comment: It's impossible to advise on a measure without knowing your table(s) structure. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I think is to add a Measure **Right click on table > Add measure**:

```
'MesaureAvg
AVERAGE('YourTableName'[ColumnName])
```

Then put in a visual in your PowerBI report with `MeasureAvg` and the `Date` column.